# Spark DataFrame equivalent of pandas.DataFrame.set_index / drop_duplicates vs. dropDuplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The drop duplicates methods of Spark DataFrames is not working and I think it is because the index column which was part of my dataset is being treated as a column of data. There definitely are duplicates in there, I checked it by comparing `COUNT()` and `COUNT(DISTINCT())` on all the columns except the index. I'm new to Spark DataFrames but if I was using Pandas, at this point I would do `pandas.DataFrame.set_index` on that column.

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Secondly, there appears to be 2 methods on a Spark DataFrame, `drop_duplicates` and `dropDuplicates`. Are they the same?

Comment: Share some of your code which will help us understand the question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the index column to be considered while checking for the distinct records, you can drop the column using below command or select only the columns required.

```
df = df.drop('p_index') // Pass column name to be dropped

df = df.select('name', 'age') // Pass the required columns
```

drop_duplicates() is an alias for dropDuplicates().

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates

Comment: Thanks, and also for the link. What annoys me about the Spark docs is half the time when you put something into a search engine, you land on the source code rather than the docs which is useless. Okay, will prefer the drop command without the underscore then, why does it need an alias.. The key is the `subset` argument in the docs. It removes the worry about doing something to the index column.